# Problem scraping webpage using beautifulsoup and requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was previously able to use beautifulsoup and requests to scrape and parse this page:

https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=y&type=36&season=2023&month=0&season1=2023&ind=0

with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import numpy as np

def parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(start_date,end_date, URL_1):
    """
    Take a HTML stats page from fangraphs and parse it out to a 
    dataframe.
    """
    # parse input
    PITCHERS_URL = URL_1
    # request the data
    pitchers_html = requests.get(PITCHERS_URL).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pitchers_html, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "rgMasterTable"})

    # get headers
    headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    headers = []
    for header in headers_html:
        headers.append(header.text)

    # get rows
    rows = []
    rows_html = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
    for row in rows_html:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all("td"):
            row_data.append(cell.text)
        rows.append(row_data)

    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = headers)

sdate = '2022-01-01'
enddate = date.today()
enddate =enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
PITCHERS = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=y&type=36&season=2023&month=0&season1=2023&ind=0"

wRC1 = parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(sdate, enddate, PITCHERS)
```

But something changed and it is not working anymore. Can I get an idea of what happened and how can I do it now?
I want to scrape data from the table, and put it into a dataframe.

Thanks in advance,
Carlos.

Comment: My apologies, David, I thought I had pasted the code, I just edited the question, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: It is returning an empty table. Looks like something changed in the way the data is rendered and I don't understand what. The problem is must probably that I don't understand what is happening now. I hope that clarifies it and I appreciate the time you are taking on this.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that hasn't clarified anything.  If you're expecting this community to debug your code for you or add new features for you then your expectation is simply wrong.  "Here's a bunch of code, fix it for me" is not an answerable question.  If the problem is that you're not familiar with how to debug code then the solution is for you to start researching and learning how to debug code.

Comment: Got it. My apologies for taking too much of your time. I wish I was clearer on this to make the appropriate questions deemed worthy of your kindness, I'll try to improve on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that data from the table, you may want to:

- inspect XHR calls in browser's Dev tools -- Network tab
- scrape the API endpoint directly

Like below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

api_url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/major-league/data?age=&pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=y&season=2023&season1=2023&startdate=2023-03-01&enddate=2023-11-01&month=0&hand=&team=0&pageitems=99&pagenum=1&ind=0&rost=0&players=&type=36&sortdir=default&sortstat=sp_pitching'
r = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['data'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Throws  xMLBAMID    Name    Team    Season  Age     AgeR    SeasonMin   SeasonMax   W   ...     HardHit%    Q   TG  TIP     PlayerNameRoute     PlayerName  playerid    TeamName    TeamNameAbb     teamid
0   R   675911  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=27498&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    24.0    24 - 24     2023    2023    18.0    ...     0.347368    1.16556     151.000000  176.000000  Spencer Strider     Spencer Strider     27498   ATL     ATL     16
1   R   554430  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=10310&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    33.0    33 - 33     2023    2023    12.0    ...     0.366397    1.19868     151.000000  181.000000  Zack Wheeler    Zack Wheeler    10310   PHI     PHI     26
2   R   669923  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=25436&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    25.0    25 - 25     2023    2023    10.0    ...     0.412698    1.13687     151.000000  171.666656  George Kirby    George Kirby    25436   SEA     SEA     11
3   R   641154  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=17085&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    10.0    ...     0.348548    1.20833     152.000000  183.666656  Pablo Lopez     Pablo López     17085   MIN     MIN     8
4   R   543037  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=13125&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    32.0    32 - 32     2023    2023    13.0    ...     0.395626    1.27152     151.000000  192.000000  Gerrit Cole     Gerrit Cole     13125   NYY     NYY     9
5   R   645261  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=18684&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    7.0     ...     0.401434    1.21491     152.000000  184.666656  Sandy Alcantara     Sandy Alcantara     18684   MIA     MIA     20
6   R   668678  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=19291&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    16.0    ...     0.456722    1.30044     152.000000  197.666656  Zac Gallen  Zac Gallen  19291   ARI     ARI     15
7   R   669203  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=19361&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    28.0    28 - 28     2023    2023    9.0     ...     0.326489    1.22296     151.000000  184.666656  Corbin Burnes   Corbin Burnes   19361   MIL     MIL     23
8   R   621107  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=13774&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    29.0    29 - 29     2023    2023    15.0    ...     0.347732    1.10307     152.000000  167.666672  Zach Eflin  Zach Eflin  13774   TBR     TBR     12
9   R   605400  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=16149&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    30.0    30 - 30     2023    2023    12.0    ...     0.381323    1.19868     151.000000  181.000000  Aaron Nola  Aaron Nola  16149   PHI     PHI     26
10  R   592332  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=14107&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    32.0    32 - 32     2023    2023    11.0    ...     0.432802    1.13907     151.000000  172.000000  Kevin Gausman   Kevin Gausman   14107   TOR     TOR     14
11  R   642547  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=18679&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    12.0    ...     0.370277    1.07726     151.000000  162.666656  Freddy Peralta  Freddy Peralta  18679   MIL     MIL     23
12  R   680694  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=24586&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    26.0    26 - 26     2023    2023    11.0    ...     0.433014    1.01104     151.000000  152.666656  Kyle Bradish    Kyle Bradish    24586   BAL     BAL     2
13  R   657376  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=19899&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    9.0     ...     0.413043    1.00000     151.000000  150.999994  Clarke Schmidt  Clarke Schmidt  19899   NYY     NYY     9
14  R   656605  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=17594&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    12.0    ...     0.339806    1.20971     151.000000  182.666672  Mitch Keller    Mitch Keller    17594   PIT     PIT     27
15  R   543243  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=12768&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    33.0    33 - 33     2023    2023    8.0     ...     0.394628    1.14474     152.000000  174.000000  Sonny Gray  Sonny Gray  12768   MIN     MIN     8
16  R   453286  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=3137&position=P"...   - - -   2023    38.0    38 - 38     2023    2023    13.0    ...     0.369347    1.01104     151.000000  152.666664  Max Scherzer    Max Scherzer    3137    - - -   2 Tms   0
17  R   656302  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=18525&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    7.0     ...     0.421634    1.08553     152.000000  165.000000  Dylan Cease     Dylan Cease     18525   CHW     CHW     4
18  R   518876  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=11156&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    34.0    34 - 34     2023    2023    11.0    ...     0.402913    1.04605     152.000000  159.000000  Merrill Kelly   Merrill Kelly   11156   ARI     ARI     15
19  R   621244  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=14168&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    29.0    29 - 29     2023    2023    11.0    ...     0.353057    1.17881     151.000000  178.000000  Jose Berrios    José Berríos    14168   TOR     TOR     14
20  L   579328  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=20633&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    32.0    32 - 32     2023    2023    10.0    ...     0.417234    1.05077     151.000000  158.666656  Yusei Kikuchi   Yusei Kikuchi   20633   TOR     TOR     14
21  R   657277  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=17995&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    26.0    26 - 26     2023    2023    10.0    ...     0.452007    1.33113     151.000000  201.000000  Logan Webb  Logan Webb  17995   SFG     SFG     30
22  R   669302  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=22250&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    26.0    26 - 26     2023    2023    13.0    ...     0.449704    1.18543     151.000000  179.000000  Logan Gilbert   Logan Gilbert   22250   SEA     SEA     11
23  L   657006  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=17312&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    16.0    ...     0.363057    1.09272     151.000000  165.000000  Justin Steele   Justin Steele   17312   CHC     CHC     17
24  R   622491  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=15689&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    30.0    30 - 30     2023    2023    14.0    ...     0.421371    1.24724     151.000000  188.333328  Luis Castillo   Luis Castillo   15689   SEA     SEA     11
25  L   666200  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=19959&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    25.0    25 - 25     2023    2023    10.0    ...     0.401806    1.09430     152.000000  166.333328  Jesus Luzardo   Jesús Luzardo   19959   MIA     MIA     20
26  R   608337  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=15474&position=P...   - - -   2023    28.0    28 - 28     2023    2023    8.0     ...     0.415948    1.12527     151.666667  170.666664  Lucas Giolito   Lucas Giolito   15474   - - -   3 Tms   0
27  R   458681  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=2520&position=P"...   - - -   2023    36.0    36 - 36     2023    2023    12.0    ...     0.390196    1.13687     151.000000  171.666664  Lance Lynn  Lance Lynn  2520    - - -   2 Tms   0
28  R   571945  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=9803&position=P"...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    34.0    34 - 34     2023    2023    7.0     ...     0.425566    1.20751     151.000000  182.333328  Miles Mikolas   Miles Mikolas   9803    STL     STL     28
29  R   502171  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=6562&position=P"...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    35.0    35 - 35     2023    2023    7.0     ...     0.432203    1.00221     151.000000  151.333328  Alex Cobb   Alex Cobb   6562    SFG     SFG     30
30  R   665152  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=19350&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    12.0    ...     0.413442    1.08609     151.000000  164.000000  Dean Kremer     Dean Kremer     19350   BAL     BAL     2
31  L   605483  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=13543&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    30.0    30 - 30     2023    2023    14.0    ...     0.342711    1.14474     152.000000  174.000000  Blake Snell     Blake Snell     13543   SDP     SDP     29
32  L   676664  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=23429&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    27.0    27 - 27     2023    2023    5.0     ...     0.373695    1.08168     151.000000  163.333328  JP Sears    JP Sears    23429   OAK     OAK     10
33  L   664285  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=17295&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    29.0    29 - 29     2023    2023    12.0    ...     0.448940    1.24123     152.000000  188.666672  Framber Valdez  Framber Valdez  17295   HOU     HOU     21
34  R   450203  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=4676&position=P"...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    39.0    39 - 39     2023    2023    14.0    ...     0.387615    1.07506     151.000000  162.333328  Charlie Morton  Charlie Morton  4676    ATL     ATL     16
35  R   605135  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=12304&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    34.0    34 - 34     2023    2023    14.0    ...     0.351402    1.22958     151.000000  185.666656  Chris Bassitt   Chris Bassitt   12304   TOR     TOR     14
36  R   543475  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=7593&position=P"...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    32.0    32 - 32     2023    2023    4.0     ...     0.350459    1.09649     152.000000  166.666656  Jordan Lyles    Jordan Lyles    7593    KCR     KCR     7
37  R   592836  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=11836&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    30.0    30 - 30     2023    2023    15.0    ...     0.405462    1.05740     151.000000  159.666656  Taijuan Walker  Taijuan Walker  11836   PHI     PHI     26
38  L   666129  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=21844&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    25.0    25 - 25     2023    2023    9.0     ...     0.448889    1.02412     152.000000  155.666656  Braxton Garrett     Braxton Garrett     21844   MIA     MIA     20
39  R   502043  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=10123&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    35.0    35 - 35     2023    2023    14.0    ...     0.446655    1.19205     151.000000  180.000000  Kyle Gibson     Kyle Gibson     10123   BAL     BAL     2
40  R   673540  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=31838&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    30.0    30 - 30     2023    2023    11.0    ...     0.394737    1.02870     151.000000  155.333328  Kodai Senga     Kodai Senga     31838   NYM     NYM     25
41  L   656756  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=16511&position=P...   - - -   2023    30.0    30 - 30     2023    2023    9.0     ...     0.373563    1.16336     151.000000  175.666664  Jordan Montgomery   Jordan Montgomery   16511   - - -   2 Tms   0
42  R   693821  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=27779&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    24.0    24 - 24     2023    2023    12.0    ...     0.404762    1.10817     151.000000  167.333328  Bryce Elder     Bryce Elder     27779   ATL     ATL     16
43  R   670912  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=22487&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    25.0    25 - 25     2023    2023    8.0     ...     0.391919    1.10375     151.000000  166.666656  Johan Oviedo    Johan Oviedo    22487   PIT     PIT     27
44  R   641540  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=19409&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    28.0    28 - 28     2023    2023    10.0    ...     0.411017    1.03974     151.000000  156.999992  Dane Dunning    Dane Dunning    19409   TEX     TEX     13
45  R   663903  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=25377&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    26.0    26 - 26     2023    2023    8.0     ...     0.484375    1.05044     152.000000  159.666656  Brady Singer    Brady Singer    25377   KCR     KCR     7
46  L   571578  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=9323&position=P"...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    33.0    33 - 33     2023    2023    10.0    ...     0.434326    1.12500     152.000000  171.000000  Patrick Corbin  Patrick Corbin  9323    WSN     WSN     24
47  L   607536  <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=16256&position=P...   <a href="leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all...   2023    30.0    30 - 30     2023    2023    6.0     ...     0.433333    1.03091     151.000000  155.666656  Kyle Freeland   Kyle Freeland   16256   COL     COL     19

48 rows × 430 columns
```

​
Please check [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/), as well as [Requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have learned a lot from it, I appreciate it.